# Implementing chat application with Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, web-applications, chat

I have developed my web application by using Java EE framework EJB 3, at front using JSF. 
Now I plan to add chat tool to my web application. All online users can chat with each other.

Can you please guide me which tool I should use to Integrate it with Java EE to develop my chat application? I also appreciate if you provide code or any link.

Comment: did you look at related topics here on SO? eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582097/java-chat-application

Comment: what have you tried so far? there's no such recipe. You should pick up your concepts and develop your chat.

Comment: I would have a look at these http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/chat-servers Claros may be the best choice.

Answer (score 5):

1- You have to install a pre developed Chat server. There is many available solutions I advice you to choose Ejabberd ( http://www.ejabberd.im/ ). It's a chat server implemented using Erlang and is considered as a highly scalable server. It's the same as facebook chat server, note that facebook used at the beginning only one server to handle all its chat traffic all over the world.

2- You have to integrate a js chat client that will communicate with the chat server. There is also a cool open source solution for that called ijab ( http://code.google.com/p/ijab/ ). You have just to configure it to connect with your server.

3- To add friends and manage interactions between users, you can use a java jabber library and there are many. This library will be used to connect to ejabberd server. You can choose one of the java clients but there are many.

You'll encounter many problems in the configuration of chat so don't under estimate it

Answer (score 2):

Link: Building a centralized connection-oriented [Java Chat Server](https://web.archive.org/web/20150906172126/http://www.cn-java.com/download/data/book/socket_chat.pdf). This tutorial also provides a good overview on socket/network programming.