# Chat application in Java web

Tags: java, jsf, glassfish, chat

I want to implement a chatting application in my web application that I'm developing. I'm using JSF with backing beans and Glassfish 3.0 server. But I don't have an idea how to start and where to start from. I want to know what are my options and possiblities! 
Thanks very much.

Comment: Search for "chat applications for the web" in a search engine. You will find a couple of interesting links in the first page. Your question is way too general and lacks investigation.

Comment: This to me is far too vague a question.  In a(ny) Turing-complete language, your "options and possibilities" are essentially infinite, and definitely innumerable.  If you don't have a specific issue to be addressed, then SO isn't really the right arena to address this question.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260110/implement-chat-application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may look at http://www.web-tech-india.com/software/jsp_chat.php to get an idea about the application. The source code is also provided on the page. Read, Download, Experiment and Learn! Once you get an idea, you can always replace JSP with JSF.

Comment: Thanx kartz! but I don't have experience in php! is it possible to work php with jsf??

Comment: JSF belongs to Java/JEE tech-stack and not PHP. So, you can't combine the two.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use ZK, you can have a look at their chat demo and further develop it.
Check [this](http://www.zkoss.org/zkchat/) (you can also download the app).