# JSF Chat example

Tags: java, jsf, chat

**I have** developed a JSF Web Application and now I would like to add a chat to it. The problem is that I do no know how to do this. AJAX polling(checking every 20 seconds for a message) seems to me a bad idea(please correct me if I'm wrong), so I would like to go with some kind of `Comet`(streaming would be perfect, but I don't mind if it's long polling). As you might suspect, the needed language is `Java`.

**I have tried** using `Grizzly`, but I couldn't find an example for JSF, only some using servlets. Then I have tried using `JMS` with a `ManagedBean`, but I still don't know how to bring the message on the front end(make the actual push). Some have suggested `Atmosphere`, but there is a lot of bragging(that it fits JSF), but the lack of real examples has made me doubt about it. Of course, I'm not refusing any of these technologies, it's just that I don't know how to use them.

**I don't want** to use some JSF extension(like RichFaces, IceFaces etc), because it doesn't seem right to use another implementation just for one feature. I don't have time for a lot of study, so looking in the sources of these frameworks is also out of the question.

**What I need** is a fully functional chat example(or a great, working tutorial) that should satisfy my needs. And this as fast as possible.

**Bonus** Because I really need really fast a very good answer, I promise that if there will be some good information(enough to make me accept it) within <= 24 hours(hopefully less), when I will be able to(in 2 days) I'll give that user a bounty.

Comment: have you looked here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260110/implementing-chat-application-with-java-ee

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I had not mentioned it, but everything should be in Java and/or JavaScript. Thanks anyway.

Comment: using that link I've found [java open source chat servers](http://www.java-sources.net/open-source/chat-servers) and [kryonet](http://code.google.com/p/kryonet/) a library to handle network communication (can be used for a chat application!) also in Java. You should do more research.

Comment: How about this http://stackoverflow.com/a/9886212/617373 all that left is to do a very simle js timer a poll like... I recommed the flot jquery charting library http://code.google.com/p/flot/

Comment: @Daniel it's chat, not chart. I want the people to be able to talk to each other :)

Comment: @Dragos How did you do it in the end ? Did you go for cometId ? An answer in the big lines to give me a rough idea would be awesome

Comment: @Ced I just dropped the idea. I do not really remember why. Sorry, I cannot help you.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [cometD](http://cometd.org/). You can find a basic chat implementation in the Demos.

**PROs**:

- It's very powerful (highly performant) and simple to use
- Well documented
- Runs on any Servlet 2.5+ compliant container
- Integrates well with the most used Javascript frameworks jQuery and Dojo

**CONs**:

- There aren't yet high - availability clustering solutions (however there are clustering solutions, but there is no built-in recovery of the state if one node crashes)
- It's not fully CDI - EJB compliant. This means that you need to use constructors, getters and setters in order to make it available in a Java EE 6 bean. You cannot inject it (this is not a real limitation, it's just an estethic one).

Comment: There is no JSF demo. They don't specify anything about this framework.

Comment: @Dragos You are right. But the only difference between what you are looking for and the chat example in cometD, is the UI. The server part can be used entirely.