# chat application using xmpp developed using worklight

Tags: push-notification, xmpp, chat, ibm-mobilefirst, xmppframework

we are trying to develop an application(iOs, Android) using IBM worklight.
There is a requirement that the application has a feature to chat with other members.

can we directly make use of worklight push services to develop this chat app?
while searching I came across XMPP protocal and XMPP server and client concept to achieve this in android and ios apps. can we configure worklight server to make use of XMPP server and developed apps as Xmpp client?

Don't know weather I am hitting the right point in asking this question?

If any one of you have knowledge on usage of these technologies please point me to right resources.

Answer (score 1):

Worklight uses the HTTP protocol for the app to communicate to the Worklight server. To use XMPP, you will have to implement it yourself.

Push notifications are a different story altogether. You can use Worklight to send push notifications to notify users when a chat message is available but this has no relation to the XMPP protocol.

Comment: "To use XMPP, you will have to implement it yourself."
can you elaborate on implementation ?
any known implementations/ place to look for ?

Comment: A quick google search for 'xmpp implementation in javascript' and 'download xmpp server' yields the following links 
http://strophe.im/strophejs/?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter
http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/servers/

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications maybe be used when the application is not in foreground so that you want to get the attention of the user and tell him that you've got a new message. 
If you want to implement chat this is another history and worklight has nothing to do with it. you can integrate with third party chat servers (that implement XMPP). Please see my answer on this question [Implementing chat application with Java EE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260110/implementing-chat-application-with-java-ee/5260196#5260196)